# Laravel 4 - controller ReflectionException Class / does not exist

Tags: php, reflection, laravel, frameworks, laravel-4

When attempting to load the page, I'm getting the error that the ReflectionException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php485, could use some insight on what is causing this error.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('contact', 'Pages@contact');
```

**laravel\app\controllers\PagesController.php**

```
<?php
class PagesController extends BaseController {
public function contact()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your controller name:

```
 Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
```